# why am I having 404 error on the cloned project

Tags: laravel

If I start new Laravel project everything is working fine (laravel new project for example) but my cloned projects have 404 error

1.project cloned 
2.env coppied
3.vendor composer install
4.key:generated

I can notice that vendor folder and .env file are gray color not white as other files.
In my created project all the folders and files are the same color

Comment: Can you provide some more information? So you clone a project from Git? Does the project you clone work for someone else? What is the route you are trying to access? Does this route exist in your web.php (or other routes file)? Have you run `php artisan route:list` to see which routes are registered?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James. 
Your answer opened my eyes. 
I deleted the home route for some reason and I was trying to access that route all the time. It was not active.
When I tried another route it was all good. 
It was working all the time ...

Thanks